# copy an image an refresh in the folder

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010, file, c#-4.0

My VS 2010 doesn´t refresh the image that I copied with File.Copy(source, dest) in a folder. If i check the folder in the windows explorer the image already exist in the visual studio path, but if I check in the Visual Explorer, don´t show the image and I can´t work with this image in the code. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you talking about an ASP.NET Web Site "project"?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does not take its solution/project items from what is in the filesystem.

Rather, it takes it from the solution and project files.  Try adding the file to your solution or project (solution explorer: context menu on solution/project node, Add, Existing File)

Comment: You need to write the linking into your .csproj file or .sln file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is use the Show All Files feature in your Solution Explorer.

In Visual Studio, go to the Solution Explorer pane and look for the Show All Files icon. Click on the icon, and it will show all the files that are in the folders but not included in your solution.

Right-click on the files you want to add, and then click "Include in project".